# Floating point exception while convert a cv::Mat image into a vector<float> type

Tags: opencv, floating-point, ros

I want to save the cv:Mat image into a vector type?
I wrote a function, but I always get the error message.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
    #include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
    #include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
    using namespace std;

    #ifdef _OPENMP
    #include <omp.h>
    #endif

    # define IM_X 200
    # define IM_Y 200
    //Globale Variablen:
    cv::Mat image;
    cv::Mat resize_image;

    //Funktionen:
    string convertInt(int number);
    vector<float> MatToFloatVec(const cv::Mat& mat) ;

    void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
    {
      try
      {
        cv::imshow("view", cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image);
        cv::waitKey(30);
      }
      catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
      {
        ROS_ERROR("Could not convert from '%s' to 'CV_32FC1'.", msg->encoding.c_str());
      }
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {

        /*
          ROS-Image Subscriber--> siehe Tutorial!!
        */
        ros::init(argc, argv, "image_listener");
        ros::NodeHandle nh;
        cv::namedWindow("view");
        cv::startWindowThread();
        image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
        image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/image_raw", 1, imageCallback);

        ROS_INFO_STREAM("Hier vor Grey");
        std::vector<float>test  = MatToFloatVec(image);
    }
    vector<float> MatToFloatVec(const cv::Mat& mat)
    {
        return vector<float>(mat.begin<uchar>(), mat.end<uchar>());
    }
```

I always get the error message:
[ INFO] [1433244615.907292392]: Hier vor Grey
Floating point exception (core dumped)

What's the problem?

Can anybody help me

Comment: Have you looked at the core dump? Which line does this happen on?

Comment: it happens when the function MatToFloatVec is called

Comment: Try simplifying your code to the bare essential to expose the problem lines.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<>` has two ctors accepting two values:

1. size + default val.
2. begin + end iterators.

You are passing `uchar` iterators where presumably, `float` iterators are expected.

Also, where in the code does it say that `image` is `8UC1`?

Comment: It surprises me that this code compiles, because of this.

Answer (score 0):

No I changed the method and now it is working.

```
vector<float> MatToFloatVec(const cv::Mat& mat)
{
    std::vector<float> array;    
    array.assign((float*)mat.datastart, (float*)mat.dataend);
    return array;
}
```